# input[type=checkbox]:checked content toggle not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

not sure if I should be asking this here or in WebMasters...
I have an HTML block used within a Jive-N instance and in the block I have a number of DIVs with content that is hidden until the heading is clicked.  Much like an accordian or collapsible.
You can see it in action on [this codepen.](http://codepen.io/whitenoise83/pen/XjbvzZ)

It uses the input[type=checkbox]:checked CSS element to toggle the display of content and is working fine on every browser except Safari... I've only just been made aware of this and how it is actually a big issue for one of our firms that run Macs and use Safari as their primary browser.

Does anyone know how to fix or adapt so it works with Safari as well as the others it already works in (IE/Edge, FireFox, Chrome and Opera).
I've tried using

```
.ln-toggle-box + label ~ div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ln-toggle-box:checked + label ~ div {
  display: block;
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

instead of

```
.ln-toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ln-toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

but it makes things break across all browsers.

I'm not against using an entirely different method, but it HAS to be HTML+CSS based and cannot use JS or jquery as Jive strips that out.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Safari? Mobile Safari on iOS, desktop Safari on macOS, or the long abandoned Safari for Windows?

Comment: the Mac office is Safari on MacOS (el capitan I beleive).
I'm testing here on my laptop using Safari for Windows 5.1.7

Comment: Have you confirmed it on the Mac Safari, which is many years and versions newer than the abandoned Windows one?

Comment: I have.  TeamViewered onto one of those new iMacs in the Mac only office and the issue is present in Safari.
Tested it with FireFox on the same Mac and there is no issue.  So definitely Safari related.